# Converting String to JSON

Tags: javascript, json, serialization, redis

I am a newbie to javascript, and I am trying to convert the redis-cli INFO command output to JSON. The string, I am trying to convert to JSON is something like this

```
    "redis_version:2.4.8\r\nredis_git_sha1:b85ba5fb\r\nredis_git_dirty:0\r\narch_bits:64\r\nmultiplexing_api:kqueue\r\ngcc_version:4.2.1\r\nprocess_id:6403\r\nuptime_in_seconds:963411\r\nuptime_in_days:11\r\nlru_clock:815387\r\nused_cpu_sys:67.32\r\nused_cpu_user:91.89\r\nused_cpu_sys_children:42.23\r\nused_cpu_user_children:132.57\r\nconnected_clients:2\r\nconnected_slaves:1\r\nclient_longest_output_list:0\r\nclient_biggest_input_buf:0\r\nblocked_clients:0\r\nused_memory:162549360\r\nused_memory_human:155.02M\r\nused_memory_rss:147972096\r\nused_memory_peak:191943360\r\nused_memory_peak_human:183.05M\r\nmem_fragmentation_ratio:0.91\r\nmem_allocator:libc\r\nloading:0\r\naof_enabled:1\r\nchanges_since_last_save:1\r\nbgsave_in_progress:1\r\nlast_save_time:1350325258\r\nbgrewriteaof_in_progress:0\r\ntotal_connections_received:187\r\ntotal_commands_processed:269264\r\nexpired_keys:180\r\nevicted_keys:0\r\nkeyspace_hits:202518\r\nkeyspace_misses:11675\r\npubsub_channels:0\r\npubsub_patterns:0\r\nlatest_fork_usec:2198\r\nvm_enabled:0\r\nrole:master\r\naof_current_size:159904546\r\naof_base_size:158667118\r\naof_pending_rewrite:0\r\naof_buffer_length:0\r\naof_pending_bio_fsync:0\r\nslave0:127.0.0.1,62716,online\r\ndb0:keys=356937,expires=0\r\n"
```

Any pointers on how to convert this to a JSON object is highly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can just do something simple like this:

```
​var fields = str.split('\r\n'), result = {};
for(var i = 0, len = fields.length; i < len; ++i) {
    var props = fields[i].split(':');
    if(props.length === 2) {           
        result[props[0]] = props[1];
    }
}

console.log(result);​​​​
console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
```

I created a jsfiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/uHtT3/1/.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use something like [webdis](http://webd.is/#json) for same purpose?

By default, Webdis replies are JSON objects containing a single item, mapping the requested command name to the Redis reply. The following JSON types are used:

```
Redis string → JSON string (GET, LPOP...)
Redis multi-bulk data → JSON list (LRANGE, SMEMBERS...)
Redis integer → JSON integer (INCR...)
Redis status, error → list [bool, string] (PING, SET...)
```

The ?jsonp query string parameter adds an optional wrapping function, transforming the reply into a JSONP call. This makes it possible to include Webdis in Javascript apps.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using **eval**?

```
eval('[{"'+<yourString>+'"}]');
```

**edit**

```
eval('({"'+<yourString>+'"})');
```

where  could be a json as a string, for example:

```
"a: 21, b:23"
```

this works for me

```
var yourString = "redis_version:2.4.8\r\nredis_git_sha1:b85ba5fb\r\nredis_git_dirty:0\r\narch_bits:64\r\nmultiplexing_api:kqueue\r\ngcc_version:4.2.1\r\nprocess_id:6403\r\nuptime_in_seconds:963411\r\nuptime_in_days:11\r\nlru_clock:815387\r\nused_cpu_sys:67.32\r\nused_cpu_user:91.89\r\nused_cpu_sys_children:42.23\r\nused_cpu_user_children:132.57\r\nconnected_clients:2\r\nconnected_slaves:1\r\nclient_longest_output_list:0\r\nclient_biggest_input_buf:0\r\nblocked_clients:0\r\nused_memory:162549360\r\nused_memory_human:155.02M\r\nused_memory_rss:147972096\r\nused_memory_peak:191943360\r\nused_memory_peak_human:183.05M\r\nmem_fragmentation_ratio:0.91\r\nmem_allocator:libc\r\nloading:0\r\naof_enabled:1\r\nchanges_since_last_save:1\r\nbgsave_in_progress:1\r\nlast_save_time:1350325258\r\nbgrewriteaof_in_progress:0\r\ntotal_connections_received:187\r\ntotal_commands_processed:269264\r\nexpired_keys:180\r\nevicted_keys:0\r\nkeyspace_hits:202518\r\nkeyspace_misses:11675\r\npubsub_channels:0\r\npubsub_patterns:0\r\nlatest_fork_usec:2198\r\nvm_enabled:0\r\nrole:master\r\naof_current_size:159904546\r\naof_base_size:158667118\r\naof_pending_rewrite:0\r\naof_buffer_length:0\r\naof_pending_bio_fsync:0\r\nslave0:127.0.0.1".replace(/\r\n/g, ",").replace(/:/g, ": '").replace(/,/g, "' ,")+"'";
eval('({'+yourString+'})');
```

or if you want to avoid using **eval** use **JSON.parse**

```
JSON.parse(yourString);
```

Comment: Same result using the string in the original question.